# Algoritmo de Anti-Aliasing em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo, imagem

Estou usando o método `setRenderingHints` proveniente da biblioteca awt para fazer anti-aliasing. O método proporciona uma melhora significativa nos objetos arredondados em 2D. Como o algoritmo funciona? Quais as semelhanças e as diferenças entre o anti-aliasing usado em letras e o aplicado em objetos? Queria implementar um próprio com melhorias.

Comment: Você quer saber como é feito o anti-aliasing em um contexto geral ou quer saber como ele é aplicado para o caso específico de formas arredondadas no java? Aliás, quais formas arredondadas? Caracteres de texto? Desenho vetorial? Texturas gradientes?

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra tentar facilitar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Estratégias para o *anti-aliasing*

O algoritmo de *anti-aliasing* em geral não é muito complexo, mas ele torna-se complexo quando você entra nos detalhes mais sórdidos e nas otimizações. Para efeitos de comparação vamos começar com um algoritmo simples sem *anti-aliasing*, que vou denominar de **A**:

> **A**: Para cada pixel que você analisa para decidir qual é a sua cor, você verifica dentro de qual forma geométrica este pixel está e aplica a cor correspondente.

E agora com *anti-aliasing*, vamos fazer uma algoritmo **B**:

> **B**: Para cada pixel que você analisa para decidir qual é a cor, você verifica qual é a fração de sua área que está em cada uma das formas geométricas e então obtém a cor correspondente de cada uma das formas geométricas e aplica a cor correspondente a média ponderada pelas áreas.

O algoritmo basicamente é isso. É óbvio que ele se torna mais complicado quando você começa a aplicar degradês, texturas, transparências e translucências, reflexão, etc. Uma forma simples de se lidar com esta complexidade é usar uma técnica chamada *supersampling*, criando então o algoritmo **C**:

> **C**: Subdivida cada pixel em um número suficiente de subpixels e aplique o algoritmo **A** para cada subpixel. No fim, a cor do pixel resultante será a média das cores dos subpixels.

O resultado deste algoritmo **C** deverá ser idêntico ou quase idêntico ao do algoritmo **B**, porém mantendo-se a simplicidade do algoritmo **A**. O problema é que o desempenho dele é bem pior devido ao grande número de subpixels, mas existe bastante espaço para efetuar-se otimizações e eliminar a necessidade de computar-se subpixels com cores sabidamente idênticas, além de muitas outras possíveis otimizações.

Além disso, para calcular o número suficiente de subpixels do algoritmo **C**, normalmente o número de tons diferente que cada componente de cor (vermelho, verde ou azul) pode assumir é um limite superior para tal número. Ou seja, na maioria dos casos, aonde cada componente é representado com um byte variando de 0 a 255, então dividir um pixel em 256 subpixels (16x16) é suficiente, mas talvez este número seja exagerado e você queira subdividir em um número menor de subpixels.

## *Anti-aliasing* em monitores LCD

Também tenho que dizer que o algoritmo usado em monitores e telas LCD é diferente do CRT. No CRT o algoritmo é basicamente o **B** ou o **C**. No LCD, se você for fazer *anti-aliasing* de uma linha diagonal preta em um fundo branco, ou então de letras, e você der um *screenshot* na imagem resultante (tecla <kbd>prt scr</kbd>) e dar um zoom nela, o *anti-aliasing* apresentará cores bem diferentes das que seriam esperadas sem o *anti-aliasing*. Eis aqui um *screenshot* do texto "LCD" de cor preta em fundo branco em zoom de 500%, ao lado da imagem original para provar isso:

[image: LCD]

Isso ocorre porque o algoritmo do LCD tem uma diferença significativa para o algoritmo **C** delineado anteriormente: ele considera que os subpixels não são iguais aos pixels que podem assumir qualquer cor. No LCD, os subpixels são monocromáticos, sendo que pelo menos no meu caso, os subpixels azuis estão na parte mais a direita do pixel, os vermelhos na parte mais a esquerda e os verdes no centro. Ao conhecer-se a disposição das cores dos subpixels, é possível efetuar-se este tipo de *anti-aliasing*.

## Composição de cores

É importante ter em mente que embora o branco seja o resultado da soma do vermelho, do verde e do azul, isso não significa que cada uma destas três cores representa um terço do branco. Isso não é verdade, e pode ser percebido facilmente de forma empírica ao notar-se que o verde puro é brilhante, enquanto que o vermelho puro é fosco e o azul puro é escuro.

Na verdade, a proporção exata da composição da luz branca depende da disposição das diferentes células receptoras na retina do olho do observador, condições de saúde, cansaço, idade e stress do observador, das condições de iluminação, do brilho e contraste da tela, do ângulo e direção entre o plano da tela e a linha de visada do observador, do tipo da tela (reflexiva ou anti-reflexiva, CRT, LED, plasma, LCD, retroprojetor, kindle, etc), entre muitas outras variáveis, podendo até mesmo variar de um olho para outro em uma mesma pessoa com visão normal e saudável.

Mas, desconsiderando-se estas variáveis que estão fora do controle do programador e pressupondo que o usuário tenha uma visão saudável e esteja usando uma tela de boa qualidade em um ambiente com iluminação adequada, há uma fórmula que vi em um livro uma vez há alguns anos que dava a seguinte proporção:

> [image: Branco = 0,290 * vermelho + 0,599 * verde + 0,111 * azul]

É uma pena que não lembro o título, mas o bfavaretto deu três referências para isso nos comentários: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470599/how-to-calculate-brightness-of-rgb-color) e [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast), embora existam pequenas variações nos fatores exatos.

Ter em mente estes fatores da composição do brilho é importante para o caso de você quiser fazer um algoritmo de *anti-aliasing* que considere que os subpixels têm diferentes cores.

Essa mesma fórmula dada acima para a cor branca, pode ser usada para medir-se o brilho de uma determinada cor a partir de seus componentes vermelho, verde e azul. De acordo com [esta página](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx), a fórmula recomendada pela W3C (parecida com essa anterior) é:

> [image: Brilho = 0,299 * vermelho + 0,587 * verde + 0,114 * azul]

Entretanto, essa mesma página diz que essa fórmula pode falhar ainda. Por exemplo, a cor (240, 0, 30) é um pouco mais brilhante que (80, 80, 80), sendo que por essa fórmula da W3C, a primeira teria um brilho de 75,18 enquanto que a segunda teria 80 ([image: vermelho e cinza]). O motivo disso é que o brilho é na verdade a distância que uma cor tem em relação ao preto, e não apenas a soma ponderada dos valores das suas tonalidades.

Se considerarmos todas as cores dispostas como diferentes pontos internos em um paralelepípedo onde um dos vértices é o preto, o vértice oposto é o branco, os vértices adjacentes ao preto são o vermelho, o verde e o azul e os vértices opostos a esses são o ciano, o magenta e o amarelo (nesta ordem), teríamos que uma das dimensões corresponde ao valor do componente vermelho, a outra do componente verde e a outra do componente azul. Se definirmos o tamanho de cada uma das dimensões desse paralelepípedo como a intensidade do componente da cor correspondente, então poderíamos usar a distância euclideana do ponto ocupado por uma cor qualquer dentro desse paralelepípedo até o vértice da cor preta como uma medida do brilho. Assim, para calcular a intensidade de uma cor, basta usar o teorema de Pitágoras. Se usarmos os valores da W3C, chegaríamos a [esta fórmula](http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html):

> [image: Brilho = sqrt(0,299 * (vermelho)² + 0,587 * (verde)² + 0,114 * (azul)²)]

Nesta fórmula, os brilhos das cores acima seriam 131,62 e 80.

## Conclusão

Há diferenças bastante significativas entre os algoritmos de *anti-aliasing* para formas geométricas em geral e para texto, mas não conheço bem os detalhes. No fundo, o algoritmo para *anti-aliasing* de texto consiste em converter o texto em formas geométricas e aplicar então o algoritmo para formas geométricas, mas existem várias coisas que podem ser otimizadas pelo fato de saber-se que o conteúdo da imagem é um texto a ser renderizado, o que é importante porque o texto consiste de um grande número de pequenas formas geométricas. Uma das principais otimizações realizadas é que conhecendo-se o tamanho da fonte, mantem-se as letras/caracteres do texto já pré-renderizadas em algum bitmap de memória com fundo transparente e apenas desenha-se tal bitmap sobre a área alvo.

Comment: Legal saber que ele funciona de maneira diferente em monitores diferentes. Vou tentar criar algo aqui.

Comment: Curiosa sua memória... Você não lembra o título do livro, mas lembra os fatores que deve aplicar a cada cor?! Só podia ser programador mesmo! :P

Comment: @pmgraff Acrescentei mais um parágrafo explicando qual é o número suficiente de subpixels do algoritmo C.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pois é. :)

Comment: Não por coincidência (suponho), esses fatores são os mesmos (ou quase os mesmos) usados para se calcular o brilho de determinada cor a partir de sua representação RGB ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color), [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470599/how-to-calculate-brightness-of-rgb-color]) [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast)).

Comment: @bfavaretto Não é coincidência, pois o brilho da luz branca corresponde a totalidade do brilho do vermelho, do verde e do azul. Além disso é de se esperar que diferentes pessoas apresentem fatores um pouco diferentes, uma vez que a percepção da luz é algo que pode variar de pessoa para pessoa e também varia de acordo com detalhes das capacidades ópticas de cada monitor. Aliás, em uma mesma pessoa a percepção no olho esquerdo pode ser um pouco diferente da do olho direito.

Comment: Complementando, descobri que como alguns dispositivos como Ipad, Iphone e muitos outros dispositivos móveis possuem o bitmap das letras em todos tamanhos que se pode exibir, quase não utilizando o anti-aliasing em fontes, pois "custa" menos armazenar as fontes comparando-se à processar o efeito de aliasing.