# Como comparar dois tons de cores e dar a porcentagem de similaridade (Java)?

Tags: java, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, comparação, cores

Como pegar imagens com mesmas dimensões (imagens de dois quadrados iguais) e analisar os tons delas para dizer o quão parecidas são (retornar uma porcentagem da similaridade entre os dois tons das imagens)? Isso é possível?

Eu estou fazendo o código que vai receber uma imagem e compará-la com outras imagens já definidas no código, dizendo se ela é igual a alguma das imagens. Essa parte do código, já tenho. O problema é que agora queria não apenas dizer se ela é igual, mas quantos % ela é igual as imagens definidas. E o tipo de código que estou fazendo é voltado para imagens com as mesmas proporções, tanto a de entrada quanto a de saída. São imagens com cores únicas, apenas, e queria que o código desse, por exemplo, a similaridade entre imagem azul claro e azul escuro, rosa choque e rosa bebê.

Comment: Poderia especificar melhor o que deseja? Um exemplo dos dois quadrados, se já tem algo feito, se possui algum conhecimento sobre o assunto... Tudo isso é relevante para "nos ajudar a te ajudar".

Comment: Relacionado: [Como funciona o recurso “Buscar por imagem semelhantes” do google?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61165/como-funciona-o-recurso-buscar-por-imagem-semelhantes-do-google)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou referenciar [esta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53399/132):

> ## Composição de cores
>
> É importante ter em mente que embora o branco seja o resultado da soma do vermelho, do verde e do azul, isso não significa que cada uma destas três cores representa um terço do branco. Isso não é verdade, e pode ser percebido facilmente de forma empírica ao notar-se que o verde puro é brilhante, enquanto que o vermelho puro é fosco e o azul puro é escuro.
>
> Na verdade, a proporção exata da composição da luz branca depende da disposição das diferentes células receptoras na retina do olho do observador, condições de saúde, cansaço, idade e stress do observador, das condições de iluminação, do brilho e contraste da tela, do ângulo e direção entre o plano da tela e a linha de visada do observador, do tipo da tela (reflexiva ou anti-reflexiva, CRT, LED, plasma, LCD, retroprojetor, kindle, etc), entre muitas outras variáveis, podendo até mesmo variar de um olho para outro em uma mesma pessoa com visão normal e saudável.
>
> Mas, desconsiderando-se estas variáveis que estão fora do controle do programador e pressupondo que o usuário tenha uma visão saudável e esteja usando uma tela de boa qualidade em um ambiente com iluminação adequada, há uma fórmula que vi em um livro uma vez há alguns anos que dava a seguinte proporção:
>
> > [image: Branco = 0,290 * vermelho + 0,599 * verde + 0,111 * azul]
>
> É uma pena que não lembro o título, mas o bfavaretto deu três referências para isso nos comentários: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470599/how-to-calculate-brightness-of-rgb-color) e [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast), embora existam pequenas variações nos fatores exatos.
>
> Ter em mente estes fatores da composição do brilho é importante para o caso de você quiser fazer um algoritmo de *anti-aliasing* que considere que os subpixels têm diferentes cores.
>
> Essa mesma fórmula dada acima para a cor branca, pode ser usada para medir-se o brilho de uma determinada cor a partir de seus componentes vermelho, verde e azul. De acordo com [esta página](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx), a fórmula recomendada pela W3C (parecida com essa anterior) é:
>
> > [image: Brilho = 0,299 * vermelho + 0,587 * verde + 0,114 * azul]
>
> Entretanto, essa mesma página diz que essa fórmula pode falhar ainda. Por exemplo, a cor (240, 0, 30) é um pouco mais brilhante que (80, 80, 80), sendo que por essa fórmula da W3C, a primeira teria um brilho de 75,18 enquanto que a segunda teria 80 ([![vermelho e cinza][2]][2]). O motivo disso é que o brilho é na verdade a distância que uma cor tem em relação ao preto, e não apenas a soma ponderada dos valores das suas tonalidades.
>
> Se considerarmos todas as cores dispostas como diferentes pontos internos em um paralelepípedo onde um dos vértices é o preto, o vértice oposto é o branco, os vértices adjacentes ao preto são o vermelho, o verde e o azul e os vértices opostos a esses são o ciano, o magenta e o amarelo (nesta ordem), teríamos que uma das dimensões corresponde ao valor do componente vermelho, a outra do componente verde e a outra do componente azul. Se definirmos o tamanho de cada uma das dimensões desse paralelepípedo como a intensidade do componente da cor correspondente, então poderíamos usar a distância euclideana do ponto ocupado por uma cor qualquer dentro desse paralelepípedo até o vértice da cor preta como uma medida do brilho. Assim, para calcular a intensidade de uma cor, basta usar o teorema de Pitágoras. Se usarmos os valores da W3C, chegaríamos a [esta fórmula](http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html):
>
> > [image: Brilho = sqrt(0,299 * (vermelho)² + 0,587 * (verde)² + 0,114 * (azul)²)]
>
> Nesta fórmula, os brilhos das cores acima seriam 131,62 e 80.

Com base nisso, se o brilho de uma cor é a distância que essa cor tem da cor preta, tal como explanado acima, então podemos medir a diferença entre duas cores a partir dessa distância. A fórmula seria a última que foi dada acima, só que os valores das variáveis `vermelho`, `verde` e `azul` são as diferenças entre os valores das duas cores.

Em Java, isso seria assim:

```
public static double distanciaCores(int r1, int g1, int b1, int r2, int g2, int b2) {
    int dr = r1 - r2;
    int dg = g1 - g2;
    int db = b1 - b2;
    return Math.sqrt(0.299 * dr * dr + 0.587 * dg * dg + 0.114 * db * db);
}
```

O método [`getRGB(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) retorna em Java cores no formato [ARGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB) como um `int` (32 bits). Neste `int`, os 8 bits mais significativos são o *alpha* (opacidade), os 8 bits seguintes são o componente vermelho, depois mais 8 bits do componente verde e finalmente 8 bits do componente azul. Assim sendo, podemos sobrecarregar o método acima para trabalhar com as duas cores codificadas cada uma dentro de um `int` já pensando em usar o formato retornado pelo `getRGB` posteriormente. Métodos auxiliares para separar cada um dos componentes (ignorando-se o *alpha*) também são utilizados:

```
public static double distanciaCores(int a, int b) {
    return distanciaCores(red(a), green(a), blue(a), red(b), green(b), blue(b));
}

public static int red(int c) {
    return (c >> 16) & 0xff;
}

public static int green(int c) {
    return (c >> 8) & 0xff;
}

public static int blue(int c) {
    return c & 0xff;
}
```

Para fazer isso em uma imagem inteira, compara-se pixel por pixel e normaliza-se de acordo com a área da imagem:

```
public static double diferencaImagens(BufferedImage a, BufferedImage b) {
    int h = a.getHeight();
    int w = a.getWidth();
    if (w != b.getWidth() || h != b.getHeight()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    double dif = 0.0;

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            int c1 = a.getRGB(x, y);
            int c2 = b.getRGB(x, y);
            dif += distanciaCores(c1, c2);
        }
    }

    return dif / (h * w);
}
```

O único detalhe é que esse algoritmo só funciona bem quando os pixels da primeira imagem coincidem com o da segunda, o que é útil para medir-se imagens onde tenha versão preto e branca vs colorida, imagens utilizando filtros diferentes, diferentes brilhos e contrastes, focalização, etc. Isso não vai dar bons resultados caso as posições dos pixels não coincidam (casos de rotações, deslocamentos, ampliações e reduções de imagens, etc).

Comment: @diegofm É isso: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/176034 e isso: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/176034

Comment: Agradeço muito a explicação, entendi uma boa parte! Só fiquei confuso no segundo bloco de código, o que ele faz?

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida Resposta editada. Está melhor?

Comment: Sim, entendi! Muito obrigado!